# Reloading subviews of UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm kind of new to iPhone development so bear with me.

I have an application wherein I display a lot of data in a tableviews, edit it in a detailview etc. However, I also have a login-system.

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to reload the subviews of the NavigationController when I've logged out, or how to dealloc it completely and reinitialize it upon a succesful login.

This means that data from the last user who logged out is still present in my tableview when I log in as another user, as the data is set to reload only when the view loads for the first time.

Thankful for any and all contributions.

Comment: +1 for being the most grammatically-correct iPhone newbie question I've ever seen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several ways you could go about this; it's up to you (and without more information about your app, I can't suggest a particular solution). You might consider:

[`-viewWillAppear:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a) — this method is called on any UIViewController subclass when it's about to (re)appear as part of a UINavigationController stack (or tab bar controller, etc.). You can clear out fields, etc. This is mostly useful when a view controller *reappears* (being uncovered or switched to), because you usually create a new view controller instance each time you display one.

[Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html) and [delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18) — your view controllers (and other objects) can communicate with each other about when a logout occurs, and reconfigure themselves as necessary.

Comment: I solved it by adding an instance variable on whether to reload data in viewWillAppear, and set it to true when I logged out, it'll do for now. Marking you as the answer for useful information.